# Unityの2Dモードで2枚の画像を組み合わせたアニメーション

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

[image: 戦車画像]
2Dで戦車のゲームを作っています。
  回転、移動する本体の上に、砲塔の中心軸を固定して本体とは別々に回したいんですが可能でしょうか？
  本体の回転、移動は「移動用ジョイスティック」、砲塔の回転は「攻撃用ジョイスティック」で制御したいです。

Comment: 現状どこまでコーディングできていますか？

Comment: まだ本体にrigidbody2d付けたくらいで、全然出来てません。

Comment: ゲームの構想は結構前から建てていたんですが、Unityで作ろうと思ったのが2週間前で本二冊くらい読んだだけでUnity自体はほとんどいじってないです。